# jquery cors post request not working

Tags: jquery, rest, post, cors

I have a problem doing CORS post request.

Here is the code for the post request:

```
/**
 * function to update channel information
 * @returns {undefined}
*/
this.postNameInfo = function() {
    var channel = self.selected.split("-")[0];
    var id = channel.replace("CH","");
    $.ajax({
        url: self.ioConfigurationUrl + "/" + id,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "data": "name:" + $("#name")[0].value
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log("Change name succeed!");
            self.updateIoInfo();
            self.updateStorageInfo();
            $("#title").val($("#name")[0].value);
            self.postTitleInfo();
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Failed to change name of " + channel)
        }
    });
};
```

The server side code is here:

```
  @POST
  @Path("/{id : \\d+}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response updateIOConfig(@PathParam("id") Integer id, @QueryParam("data") String data) {
    if (!ChannelName.isValidChannel(id)) {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
    init();
    IOConfiguration ioConfig = ioConfigurationDAO.findIOConfiguration("CH" + id);
    String key = data.split(":")[0];
    String value = data.split(":")[1];
    if (!ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().isActive()) {
      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().begin();
    }
    System.out.println(data);
    if (key.equals("name")) {
      ioConfigurationDAO.changeName(ioConfig.getIoConfigurationId(), value);
      ioConfigurationDAO.getManager().getTransaction().commit();
      if (ioConfig.getDataSeriesMeta() != null && ioConfig.getDataSeriesMeta().size() != 0) {
        List<DataSeriesMeta> list = ioConfig.getDataSeriesMeta();
        DataSeriesMetaDAO dataSeriesMetaDAO = new DataSeriesMetaDAO();
        dataSeriesMetaDAO.setManager(ioConfigurationDAO.getManager());
        if (!dataSeriesMetaDAO.getManager().getTransaction().isActive()) {
          dataSeriesMetaDAO.getManager().getTransaction().begin();
        }
        for (DataSeriesMeta d : list) {
          dataSeriesMetaDAO.changeName(d.getDataSeriesMetaId(), value);
        }
        dataSeriesMetaDAO.getManager().getTransaction().commit();
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(ioConfig).build();
      }
    }...
}
```

On my server side, I am always receiving null value and the browser will give me this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://localhost:8080/aigateway/rest/ioconfiguration/1. (Reason: CORS
>   header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

It seems to me that my CORS filter is not working.

But if I am sending post request from RESTeasy to

> http://localhost:8080/aigateway/rest/ioconfiguration/1?data=name:123

It will give me a 200 OK response with the correct information like

> {"ioConfigurationId":"CH1","active":true,"name":"123","conversionType":"Linear","mInfo":5.93,"bInfo":0.32,"voltageDivide":"/4","sampleRange":"24
>   Bits","samplePeriod":10,"storeRaw":false,"storeConverted":false,"defaultGraph":"Line","title":"","unit":"","rangeLowerbound":0,"rangeUpperbound":100,"code":"function
>   conversion_CH1 (input) {\n\treturn input;\n}"}

And I can check the header, it is:

```
X-Powered-By    Undertow/1
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    origin, content-type, accept, authorization, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Server  WildFly/10
Date    Mon, 27 Mar 2017 14:41:24 GMT
Connection  keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin     *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Content-Type    application/json
Content-Length  357
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Max-Age  1209600
```

That's what I have added in my CORS filter, it's working in RESTeasy but not in my project, it's so strange, I don't know why.

For more information, here is how I set up my CORS filter:

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

  @Override
  public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
      final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
  }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>
                com.sensorhound.aigateway.ws.filters.CORSFilter
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletContainer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sensorhound.things.rest.ThingsApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletContainer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

If you need more information, I am willing to share.

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

According to NrN, I have removed *Access-Control-Allow-Credentials* field in my CORS filter, but it still don't work.

Here is the request header in my browser's network console:
**Request Header:**
Accept*/*

```
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 18
Content-Typet ext/plain
Host localhost:8080
Origin null
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
```

Here is the Response header:
**Response Header:**

```
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 9437
Content-Type text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date Tue, 28 Mar 2017 21:16:46 GMT
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 problems here.

1. In the Jquery client request you do not have the withCredentials attribute set to true, but the server is trying to respond Access-Control-Allow-Credentials as true. Place this inside the ajax call.
     **xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
   }**
2. When you set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to "true", you cannot have Access-Control-Allow-Origin as "*". You must specify a specific origin rather than the wildcard. 
   More details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials

Comment: Hi, NrN, thanks for your comment. I have removed "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" field in my filter. But it still didn't work. I provided more information about my request headers and response headers in the EDIT, have a look if you have time. Thanks!